# What nutrients are worth taking for a tendinosis?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, tendinopathy

I am wondering what nutrients are worth taking for a tendinosis.

[1] Bass, Evelyn. "[Tendinopathy: why the difference between tendinitis and tendinosis matters](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=5756777431120633976&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)." International journal of therapeutic massage & bodywork 5, no. 1 (2011): 14-17. mention:

> - Vitamin C, manganese, and zinc are all important for the synthesis of collagen production (20).
> - Vitamin B6 and Vitamin E have also been linked to tendon health (21).

They failed to indicate which type of collagen they are talking about, and ignored the importance of the alpha2(I) to alpha1(I) ratio.

What else can be useful?

Answer (score 1):

There's a paucity of experimental human data on this topic. Rodent studies such as this one http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21117902 show that glucosamine might improve healing and strength of surgically divided tendons. That might be completely irrelevant to humans.